# CMake project: targets with different definitions

Tags: compilation, cmake, dependencies, opencl

I am trying to add some OpenCL kernels to a CMake project. These need to be compiled into `.ptx` files as part of the compilation.

The kernels live in a subdirectory of the source tree, and the output should go into the binary tree. There will be one `.ptx` file for every `.cl` file.

My question is how to express this as a CMake custom command?

I tried the following, but this is derived from a custom command with a single, predefined output file - I now have many outputs with names that depend on the input.

```
set(OPENCL_CL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openclkern)
set(OPENCL_PTX_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/openclkern/ptx)
set(OPENCL_CLOPTS "-cl-nv-verbose")
set(OPENCL_COMPILER ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/linux/clcc)

file (GLOB openclkern openclkern/*.cl)

ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    OUTPUT ${OPENCL_PTX_DIR}
    COMMAND "${OPENCL_COMPILER}" ${OPENCL_CLOPTS} ${OPENCL_PTX_DIR} ${openclkern}
    DEPENDS ${openclkern}
)
```

This compilation step will be followed by another custom command to transform the `.ptx` files into a C-formatted "blob" for compilation into the final executable, so I suppose I need to end up with a `${ptxFiles}` list that I can use as the next command's `DEPENDS` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did it by constructing the list of outputs myself with a simple string replacement, which gave me a list of `.ptx` files to use as a dependency.

```
file (GLOB openclkern ${OPENCL_CL_DIR}/*.cl)

string(REPLACE ".cl" ".ptx" compiledkernels ${openclkern})

# compile .cl kernels to .ptx
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
    OUTPUT ${compiledkernels}
    COMMAND "${OPENCL_COMPILER}" ${OPENCL_CLOPTS} ${OPENCL_PTX_DIR} ${openclkern}
    DEPENDS ${openclkern}
)
```